# Call Matlab Function from C# error : The type initializer for 'tes.tambah' threw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I am getting the

> "The type initializer for 'tes.tambah' threw an exception.."

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using tes;

namespace panggil_lib_matlab
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                tambah tbh = new tambah(); 
        }
    }
}
```

and this my Matlab Code:

```
function [ hasil ] = coba( a,b )
    hasil = a+b;
end
```

I get error on this line: `tambah tbh = new tambah();` and this is the 'InnerException' message:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray' threw an exception. --->
>   System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program
>   with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)    at
>   MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray.mclmcrInitialize2(Int32
>   primaryMode)    at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray..cctor()    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR..cctor()    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at tes.tambah..cctor()

I use:

- Windows 8.1 64-bit
- Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 (32-bit, I think)
- Matlab R2015a 64-bit

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Improved some formatting and grammar, made title slightly more concise

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your application targets x64 rather than AnyCPU